# Have there ever actually been any studies proving some immunizations cause autism?

Tags: immunizations, autism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the objective arguments against immunizations for infants and children?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-objective-arguments-against-immunizations-for-infants-and-children)

I have heard a lot about autism being caused by some immunizations, but haven't found any studies actually proving this.  Have there been any?  Or have there even been any strong correlations?

Saying something like "nearly all children with autism have had immunizations" means nothing since over 98% of children have been given immunizations.  That's pretty much like saying "nearly all autistic children fit within 98% of the scope of all children".

Comment: No accepted peer reviewed research is available at this time. Some research indicating that there was a link was published but has since been debunked by peers as invalid. This question has been addressed in 2 other related questions on this site and may need to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

No. The only well known study showing a link (Wakefield) was subsequently exposed as fraudulent.

This is discussed in more detail at Skeptics SE: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/607/are-there-any-other-studies-besides-the-discredited-wakefield-studies-that-have

Comment: This is a good article on this topic: http://www.upworthy.com/it-took-studying-25782500-kids-to-begin-to-undo-the-damage-caused-by-1-doctor?g=4&c=ufb1

Comment: Its kind of ironic really; the anti-vaccine crowd keep saying that vaccines are some kind of money-making conspiracy, but Wakefield was actually in the pay of an American lawyer desperate to prop up an anti-vaccine case with some kind of evidence.

Comment: @PaulJohnson And Wakefield had developed his own single-dose measles vaccine. To get people to use that he had to discredit the existing measles vaccine, delivered as part of MMR.